# Connection to oracle databases without odbc and jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, database-connection

I want to connect to oracle 10g databases in java without help from odbc and jdbc drivers. Is there any way to do that??? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue with driver jar?

Comment: No issue. Just that I need to know if there's an alternative way to do this either using web services or anything

Comment: Without Driver how could you run connect with DB? You have to write your own driver..

Comment: Can you suggest any driver other than these two???

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan What's wrong with those two drivers?

Comment: My employer thinks it might create some security related issue and since boss is always right, let him enjoy the privilege

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan But you're the one who's in trouble. You've been given an impossible requirement, and you keep whining here, instead of accepting the truth.

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan All the Java World is using those driver while your boss telling about security issue on those driver Please BEWARE he will tell you create JAVA kind of language because JAVA also have some issue .

Comment: Laughed so hard on that one :D Anyways, guys you could surely help by suggesting an alternative driver or anything

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan There are no alternative drivers. Even if there were, your boss wouldn't accept them either. You have no alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

No. That's exactly what the JDBC drivers are for. To connect to the database.

Strictly speaking you could write your own driver (and call it something else), but that would be an immense amount of work, just because you refuse to do things the correct way.

Comment: Actually, I'm needed to do this without the help from specifically jdbc and odbc. That's why I'm asking is there an alternative for them

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan You can't connect to Oracle from Java without a suitable driver, so that's a pretty impossible requirement. Nothing stops you from generating scripts and running them through a commandline tool or TOAD, but that's a totally different thing (you're not connecting to the db).

Comment: Actually I'm interested in knowing if there exists an alternative way to establish the connection

Comment: Or may be if there's a driver or something other than these two

Comment: @IbrahimAliKhan No, there's no drivers (for Java) besides those two. They work fine too. You have absolutely no reason not to use them.

Comment: If there are no drivers may be there's some other way to establish connection

Comment: You can always establish a Socket connection to the server. That would be a stupid choice, but it's possible. Then you just need to learn to communicate with the native protocol. Hope you have plenty of time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Oracle can act as a *web service provider*.

In the 10g version, you can only publish REST XML/JSON services; in 11g, support for SOAP web services was added.

Please note that the services provided by Oracle need to be implemented in PL/SQL; essentially you would be writing stored procedures that wrap the SQL queries you normally send over JDBC. Compared to JDBC, the web service / REST API is a very different tool as it works on a higher level of abstraction. You should only use it when required (e.g. if you don't want to mix SQL with your Java code), *not* because of false beliefs about security issues with JDBC drivers.

See [this Oracle-Base article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/web-services-and-the-oracle-database#publishing-web-services) for more information.

Comment: I should've guessed this is possible (since at least Postgres can perform similar tricks). However, as you put it, this isn't about connecting to a database, but rather about a paranoid, ignorant boss.

Comment: @Kayaman, yes, publishing a web service from the DB is quite an extreme solution. I wouldn't probably ever use it with any Java-based stack, because there are better alternatives such as using JDBC, either directly or through an ORM.